# How do I add an event listener to all the childnodes of a div in and array of those div?

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, delegation

I'm teaching myself JS and trying to avoid jQuery until my JS skills are better.

Goal: add an eventlistener, for click event, to all the divs of a certain class.  Have all the child nodes of that class respond to the event.

My HTML

```
 <div class="grid-panel six columns">
            <div class="grid-panel-image">
                <i class="fa fa-css3"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-panel-title">
                <h4>css3</h4>
            </div>                  
    </div>
    <div class="grid-panel six columns">
        <div class="grid-panel-image">
            <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-panel-title">
            <h4>tamberator</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I select all the `.grid-panel` divs using this JS

```
var gridPanels = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-panel');
```

then, since that returns an array of divs with the class `.grid-panel`
I add the event listener for click as such

```
for(i=0; i<gridPanels.length; i++){
    gridPanels[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}
```

my function is this

```
 myFunction(){
    var e = event.target;

        switch(e){
            case gridPanels[0]:
            modalArray[0].setAttribute("data-modal-display", "show");
            break
            case gridPanels[1]:
            modalArray[1].setAttribute("data-modal-display", "show");
            break
        }

            console.log(e);
    }
```

This does work if I click a very specific part of the `.grid-panel`div and the `e` logs that specific element.  However, clicking any children of the div logs the `e` as the element i clicked, but the eventlistener is not applied to that element.  I'm clearly missing something here with this event delegation.  I really want the function to fire on the div clicked and all of its childnodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding correctly, but if you want to get the element to which the handler is bound in the handler, then use `this` or `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

The `event.target` represents the actual element that was clicked, which is sometimes useful as well.

Also, you should define the `event` parameter in the function. Not all browsers have it available as a global variable.

```
function myFunction(event){
    var e = this
 // var e = event.currentTarget // same as above

    switch(e){
        case gridPanels[0]:
        modalArray[0].setAttribute("data-modal-display", "show");
        break

        case gridPanels[1]:
        modalArray[1].setAttribute("data-modal-display", "show");
        break
    }

    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Wow.  That was excellent.  Thank you for correcting the event property I was using.